# Kotlin Android TV app does not appear in search results on Android TV

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console, android-tv

So I just released my first android app, so I don't know what I am doing. It was approved and officially sent to production on the Google play store and approved this morning and it live.

This is for the company I work for.

The issue I am having making the app appear in the search for multiple devices.

Here is the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.itiswritten.app

If I search for the app in a web browser it shows up in the results, but nothing for phone, or Android TV results. My question is how do I get it to display on multiple platforms.

I put some screen shots in as well to help explain what I am talking about.

The app is for Android TV. Trying to get it so I can install the TV app on TV via mobile phone.

Also when you go to all the list of apps our company has produced, it only is visible in browser as well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Expecting it to show up in the search results in the play store across mobile, and Android TV

Andrid Maniftest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.itiswritten">
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.ScheduleActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.allprogramsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.SearchActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/channel_poster_fhd"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/channel_poster_fhd"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/channel_poster_fhd"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.DetailsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.PlaybackActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.BrowseErrorActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="tv.itiswritten.app.ProgramsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```